# How do I set vim 7's html tidy options for "utf-8" encoding?

Tags: html, vim, htmltidy

I need to run tidy in vim, using the usual:

`:compile tidy`

`:make`

However, if I'm on an utf-8 file, I get errors that I don't see if I run tidy outside of vim, i.e.,

`tidy -e -q -utf8 <filename>`

I get what I'm expecting

Answer (score 1):

My Vim script skills do not go far enough to have a general solution ready, but what you can do when editing a utf-8 file:

```
:compiler tidy
:setlocal makeprg=<TAB> [and edit the tidy command line to include -utf8]
:make
```

Explanation:

":compile tidy" just executes the compiler plugin file for tidy and does setlocal to set makeprg to tidy call with some options (-q -e --gnu-emacs yes). Apparently for utf-8 files tidy needs the additional option -utf8, so you have to set this manually. Afterwards you call :make as normal.

If you are *only* editing utf8 files, you can of course edit the tidy compiler plugin file directly and hard code the -utf8 option to tidy there. Use the following to edit the plugin file

```
:e $VIMRUNTIME/compiler/tidy.vim
```

Comment: That is excellent, thanks and I confirmed it works. 

Can I modify my .vimrc instead, making this more portable?

Comment: That depends. If you are only using the tidy compiler, you can probably get away with putting "compiler tidy" and "set makeprg=..." hard coded into your .vimrc. What might be in general be a good idea is to contact the maintainer of tidy.vim (you can find the name at the top of the tidy.vim file), maybe he has some general solution to your problem.